# How to enable autologin but still require password

Tags: login, password, lock-screen, gdm, auto-login

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 14.04, using gdm display manager and gnome-shell environment and I need to achieve the following behaviour: after boot, a selected user is automatically logged in, but a password is still needed to access the session. Or in other words, after the user is automatically logged in, the screen is locked immediately.

The user login is specifically needed; it's not about starting a service at boot time (which is achievable with different means).

Is this behaviour possible? If so, how to do it in the most clean and non-hacky way? Changing the display manager or the environment is not an option.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically lock my computer after logged in via auto login](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165225/how-to-automatically-lock-my-computer-after-logged-in-via-auto-login)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable auto login.

Check whether you have installed `gnome-screensaver` by running following command.

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep gnome-screensaver
```

If it is not installed run following command to install `gnome-screensaver`.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

Add this command on Startup application.(To open startup application preferences search "Startup applications" on Unity dashboard.

`/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command -l`

[image]

This screenshot is a Unity screenshot. But this works on GNOME shell without any modification.

Latest Ubuntu version has a command called `loginctl`. You can replace startup command with below command and get the same thing done.

`loginctl lock-session`

Comment: Needed to install `gnome-screensaver`, but works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: You really want to use command `loginctl lock-session` nowadays. That will work no matter which screensaver you're using.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Thanks a lot, I updated the answer.

Comment: It seems to take a couple minutes for my Ubuntu to finally get around to running this command. Is there a way to make sure this start up application runs sooner?

Comment: On 22.04 with either command, desktop remains unlocked with a notification that says "Unable to lock; Lock was blocked by an application". I had to add a delay to get it to work: `sh -c "sleep 15 ; loginctl lock-session"`